# Is 'Timeout' class which extend 'RequestExecutionException' is same as 'OperationTimedOut' class which extends DriverException in Datastax driver?

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra-2.0

Is 'Timeout' class which extend 'RequestExecutionException' is same as 'OperationTimedOut' class which extends DriverException in Datastax driver???

I have exception coming while i do read and write using python datastax driver:
[Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message=\"Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.\" info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_QUORUM'}\"", "pid": 1065}

Is this a timeout exception or a OperationTImedOut exception??
In which cases both these type of exception comes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are distinct timeouts, but they will commonly be handled similarly by an application.

[OperationTimedOut](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-dse-driver/2.10/api/dse/#dse.OperationTimedOut) indicates that the client received no response before the client-side request timeout.

[TimeOut](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-dse-driver/2.10/api/dse/#dse.Timeout) is a coordinator timeout in which replica responses were not received before the server-side timeout.

See docs for [ReadTimeout](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-dse-driver/2.10/api/dse/#dse.ReadTimeout) and [WriteTimeout](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-dse-driver/2.10/api/dse/#dse.WriteTimeout), which also mention the `cassandra.yaml` settings that govern coordinator timeouts.

Comment: So technically their value should be same ???. I mean if my read timeout at node is say 20 seconds and even if i put timeout 60 seconds at my client side, i am just wasting 40 seconds on my client side.